# JSP/HTML / JS / CSS - How to create a cancel button in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I need to put the "save", and "cancel" functionality in the form in JSP code. Clicking on "save" should submit the form data to intended place. Clicking on "cancel" should cancel the form without submitting the data to intended place.

Thanks & Regards,

Arun Dhwaj

Comment: Please provide an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and then let us look at it for relevance to your question

Comment: provide code, and how do javascript and jquery relate to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd solved this in the following way:

**1) myInfo.jsp**

```
<form name="myForm" action="/done" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <label>Enter new name </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="edit_filed" id="name_edit" type="text" value="${obj.getfName()} &nbsp;${obj.getlName()}">

    <label>Enter new specializations </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="specializations" id="specializations_edit" type="text" value="${obj.oldSpecialization()}">

    <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="Save('myInfo_visual', 'myInfo_edit')">Save</button>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-gray" onClick="Cancel('myInfo_visual', 'myInfo_edit')"/>
</fieldset>
```

**2) myInfo.js**

```
function Save(visual, edit)
```

{
    var v = document.getElementById(visual);
    var e = document.getElementById(edit);

```
v.style.display="block";
e.style.display="none";
```

}

function Cancel(visual, edit)
{
    var v = document.getElementById(visual);
    var e = document.getElementById(edit);

```
v.style.display="block";
e.style.display="none";

return false;
```

}